# WPF Trying to create a library with custom window control but I get an Error: Cannot change AllowsTransparency after a Window has been shown

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I want to create a custom control template (on a library/separate assembly) and launch a dialog/message box based on that custom control template without needing a separate client XAML based on that custom control template.

The control template is developed as follows ...

**Control Template Class**

```
public class DialogWindow : Window
{
    #region Constructors
    static DialogWindow()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DialogWindow),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DialogWindow)));
    }

    public DialogWindow()
    {
    }

    public DialogWindow(string title, string header, string message)
    {
        Title = title;
        HeaderText = header;
        MessageText = message;
    }
        ///...
        ///the rest of the custom control class
        ///...
```

**Control Template Style**

```xml
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type customcontrols:DialogWindow}">

        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="None" />
        <Setter Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize"/>
        ...
        <!-- the rest of the control template-->
        ...
    </Style>
```

on the client application, i want to use the control template as. So much like a MessageBox type declaration but completely styled from scratch.

**Client Code**

```
        CustomControls.DialogWindow custom = new CustomControls.DialogWindow("Sample Title", "Sample Header", 
            Properties.Resources.DocumentResourceSample);
        custom.IsOKEnabled = true;
        custom.OKButtonClick += CloseDialog;
        custom.ShowDialog();
```

The complete error I get when trying to launch the dialog window is

> Error: Cannot change AllowsTransparency after a Window has been shown or WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle has been called.

I really want to set the AllowsTransparency via the custom control template style, otherwise, a thick black border appears.

What do you guys think am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you guys are interested, here's how I managed to solve this. 
I created a user control that implements the custom dialog window control as such

**CODE**

```
    public partial class CustomDialogBox : DialogWindow
    {
    public CustomDialogBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

also hooked up all the custom stuff

```
    public CustomDialogBox(string title, string header, string message)
    {
        Title = title;
        HeaderText = header;
        MessageText = message;

        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<customcontrols:DialogWindow 
    Style="{StaticResource {x:Type customcontrols:DialogWindow}}"
    >
     <Grid>
     </Grid>
</customcontrols:DialogWindow>
```

and everything seems to be working pretty well. 
I don't think this is a pretty good implementation. I am still interested if there are better approaches to this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles on this situation while trying to make a custom window class and have it styled using WPF styles, I have figured out a nice solution for solving this issue without having hard code `AllowTrasparency` inside the Window class.

I have documented and shared the code here: https://gist.github.com/aurimasniekis/53533fddefe95b04bcad37b815197b8e

P.S. This does not solve changing `AllowTrasparency` at runtime, but allows you have control of it using style at Window creation.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution to StackOverflow. Answers that merely link to external sources are not encouraged as the link is prone to loss. Please consider providing the key points of your code here directly in your answer so that if the link externally gets broken, future searchers will still be able to learn from your answer.